# Error : Flutter - Missing 'package' key attribute on element package at [com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:33:9-64

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, google-play-services

I am getting an error while build appbundle in Flutter

Error:

```
Building without sound null safety
```

For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

```
[com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2] C:\Users\theGODFATHER\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\6f829f42d3699bf76afaf5ddb99cba4b\play-services-maps-18.0.2\AndroidManifest.xml:33:9-64
 Error:
        Missing 'package' key attribute on element package at [com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:33:9-64

[com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2] C:\Users\theGODFATHER\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\6f829f42d3699bf76afaf5ddb99cba4b\play-services-maps-18.0.2\AndroidManifest.xml
 Error:
        Validation failed, exiting

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 3):

check your android-> build.gradle file

dependencies {

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'. // <- check this line
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
}
```

Comment: I have below already :

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
 classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'